# Shift+L is not working properly

Tags: materials, linked-data

I am working through the Blender tutorials by Blender Guru, and I am having trouble with linking the material of my doughnut sprinkles (objects) in Part 7 on particles; I'm using Blender 2.79b. As I go through, I have added the material to the first sprinkle. I unselect that sprinkle, then I Shift+Select the other sprinkles before selecting my sprinkle with the assigned material last (making it the active one). I press Shift+L, selected Material from the drop down menu, and all the sprinkles become unselected except the active one and none of the other sprinkles get the material assigned. I'm not sure what is going on here, and I can't find any suggestions. Now I can easily go through and select the individual sprinkles and assign the material, which is easy with a small number of objects, but if I want to create a scene with a large number of objects that are assigned the same material, that's not going to be so easy. Any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score -1):

Here is the answer:

Use CTRL+L instead of Shift+L

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! Could you elaborate a bit or add some screenshots? OP clearly had some effect when pressing Shift+L, so maybe you could explain what that did.